# Ruby: Trouble showing SQL result in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble presenting a SQL result in my View. The "Place ROI" column only shows ActiveRecord:Relation... I've researched, and I'm at a loss as to how I present the value. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the result on the Web page:

```
Horse Name      Win ROI     Wins    Total Races     Place ROI
Billy the Bull  $13.3        2       2              #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Horse:0xb494fa5c>
```

Here is the View code:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
<tr>
    <th>Horse Name</th>
    <th>Win ROI</th>
    <th>Wins</th>
    <th>Total Races</th>
    <th>Place ROI</th>
</tr>
<% Horse.with_win_roi.having("#{Horse::HORSE_WIN_ROI_SELECT} > 5 and #{Horse::HORSE_NUMBER_OF_WINS} > 1").each do |horseWinROI| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= horseWinROI.horse_name %></td>
        <td class="decimal">$<%= horseWinROI.win_roi %> </td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= horseWinROI.wins %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= horseWinROI.total_races %></td>
        <td>
            <%= Horse.only_place_roi.where("horses.id = ?", horseWinROI.id) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>           
</table>
```

Here's the Model code:

```
HORSE_WIN_ROI_SELECT = "( (sum(entries.win_payoff) - (2 * count(horses.id))) / (2 * count(horses.id) ) )"
HORSE_PLACE_ROI_SELECT = "( (sum(entries.place_payoff) - (2 * count(horses.id))) / (2 * count(horses.id) ) )"

HORSE_NUMBER_OF_WINS = "SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(entries.official_finish as int) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)"

scope :with_win_roi, -> {
    joins({:entries => {:race => [:chart,:race_level]}}).
    group("horses.id").
    select("CAST(#{HORSE_WIN_ROI_SELECT} as decimal(10,2)) as win_roi,horses.*,horses.id, #{HORSE_NUMBER_OF_WINS} as wins, #{HORSE_NUMBER_OF_RACES} as total_races").
    order("win_roi DESC")
}

scope :only_place_roi, -> {
    joins({:entries => {:race => [:chart,:race_level]}}).
    group("horses.id").
    select("CAST(#{HORSE_PLACE_ROI_SELECT} as decimal(10,2)) as place_roi")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first recommendation is [take a deeper dive into ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), as a lot of these queries are definitely not the Rails Way of doing things. You want to avoid writing SQL directly whenever possible, because doing so skips any query sanitization ActiveRecord would do for you.

And to answer your question, what's happening in your query is you're getting rows of the `horse` table with only the `place_roi` virtual column. To then *access* that column, you need to append `.place_roi` to the relation, like this:

```
Horse.only_place_roi.find(horseWinROI.id).place_roi
```

As you can see, I also changed the `where` to a `find`, since you only want one record and are finding by id.

Comment: Great answer. Worked perfectly. Thank you. I'll do the deep dive as you suggest. Thanks again for your help.